# How to detect multiple login with the same account in Meteor app

Tags: authentication, meteor, double

I'd like have a hook on the event when an user login to Meteor app from several different clients/browsers. 
I am aware of Meteor.logoutOtherClients() function which provide an action of "Log out other clients logged in as the current user". But I'd like to bind a custom handler on this even, instead of just logging the others out...

Comment: Search for *presence* on atmosphere.

Comment: @Serkan Durusoy 
_Presence_ give a status "online', 'offline' and so on, but does not detect multiple logins of current user.

Comment: You can get a count of the presences with some of those packages.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {}, {fields: {'services.resume.loginTokens': 1}}).length > 1
```

Comment: it doesn't really work as Meteor.users collection has only 1 document with this.userId. And "find" returns a cursor and not an array. "Fetch" is required to get an array, but it makes no sense as array.length will be 0 or 1...

Comment: It's pseudocode. It means to say "count the number of login tokens for this user."

Comment: Still it does not work as loginTokens stay there even when the user has logged out. You can easy check it by this code (not pseudo), run on your server:
Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).services.resume.loginTokens.length